# How to archive iOS Release to the App Store?

Tags: ios, react-native, app-store, testflight, app-store-connect

After success archiving, I'm expecting to see the window with "upload to App Store" checker, but when I click to "Distribute Content" button there are only to options: "Build products" and "Archive". Also button "Validate Content" under "Distribute Content" validate disabled.
How can I upload my app to the App Store?

Even tried to create a new project with the same identifier and add all code from the previous project, it has successfully built but also doesn't build archive properly.

P.S. I have an Apple developer license and configured bundle identifiers and provision profile at Apple Dev Portal.

[Archive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBTSI.png)

[Distribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOUlF.png)

Comment: do you see "Upload to App Store" a blue color button on right side or organizer?

Comment: @MuhammadWaqas I've added images

Comment: Are you using Xcode? If yes which version?